# Photoshop CS5: Filesize difference when saving

Tags: filesystems, images, adobe-photoshop

Photoshop says filesize will be 1.938k

[image: Photoshop says filesize will be 1.938k]

But actual filesize after saving is 2.96KB

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Update 1: To clarify, I'm talking about File > Save for Web

Update 2: I asked a friend with CS3 to do this and he was able to have exactly the same filesize. So this seems to be a CS5 bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop CS5 is not including the Metadata in the calculated size of the file.

If you set: `Metadata: None` you should get an output file of the specified size.

You will need to manually allow for the size of your "Copyright and Contact Info" metadata.

Comment: Amazing... I was losing hope and would revert to CS2 then you came... LOL thanks!

BTW what's Metadata for and how do you usually access it supposed you set it?

Comment: @IMB metadata is any data that is not actually part of the image itself.  It includes things like camera settings, time/date tags, copyright notices, etc.  You can view most (but not all) of the metadata by opening the file in Photoshop and then choosing `File > File Info...`

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop file size is printed image size in Photoshop format or aproximated disk size (real size can depend on OS, compression and other factors) as you can see in [adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7508a.html).

> Document Sizes
>
> Information on the amount of data in the image. The number on the left
>   represents the printing size of the image—approximately the size of
>   the saved, flattened file in Adobe Photoshop format. The number on the
>   right indicates the file’s approximate size, including layers and
>   channels.

Comment: It's not Document size I'm talking about but the size of the final output when using "File > Save for Web..."